# Using customBuildCallbacks.xml in an Eclipse RCP headless build

Tags: eclipse, build-process, rcp, headless

I am trying to add some custom build steps to my headless build process for an Eclipse RCP application.

I understand that the recommended way is to provide a customBuildCallbacks.xml file on the plug-in directory, and adding a link to it in the build.properties file.

```
 # This property sets the location of the customb Build callback
 customBuildCallbacks = customBuildCallbacks.xml
```

However, during the build process, this step is ignored.

Is there some set-up step I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out that this is the only thing required.... if we are using eclipse 3.3. This will not work using Eclipse 3.1